# How do I set up Facebook "ask for..." privacy setting?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

When I look at a friend's About page on Facebook, under "email" I almost always see a link that says "Ask for 's email". Likewise for a lot of other fields on that page.

How do I set it up so that it works like that for my email address as well? When editing that information, I can see options to show it to all my friends or none of my friends and things like that, but I can't see an option to turn on this "ask for" feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message will show up only for `Friends` who are able to view more than your `Public` information (therefore `Restricted` friends are excluded) but **not** the contact information in question. Reasons they might not be able to view that information are as follows:

- The friend in question is not part of a sufficiently-privileged group (eg. they are an `Acquaintance` when you set your visibility to `Friends except Acquaintances`)
- You set the `Hidden from Timeline` flag on that information

It is worth noting that even if you set both the visibility to `Public` **and** the `Hidden from Timeline` flag, then `Restricted` friends will still not see the message.